# Fresh Ubuntu 19 install : stuck in 1024.x768 resolution

Tags: display-resolution

Fresh install on PC to replace Fedora by Ubuntu
Intel 4790K, Nvidia 980 GTX plugged to a HD screen
I selected to install with Nvidia driver but after install is done, I'm stuck in 1024x768. The Display control panel does not offer any other resolution...

Comment: xrandr shows this :
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*

The display is an Asus HD display connected to the 980 GTX using an HDMI cable
Windows 10 and Fedora directly set them themselves to HD resolution with no trouble
I am using the NVidia latest proprietary driver

Comment: I have tried this but it failed :
I reinstalled Ubuntu without installing Nvidia drivers.
After the install, Nouveau driver is being used and display is OK.
I went into "Additional Drivers" and selected the latest Nvidia driver. It asks me for a Secure Boot password that "will be asked after reboot"
I reboot... and no password is asked. I login, and still no password is asked.
So I am again stuck in 1024x768.

The SecureBoot password is not asked after reboot. This is a fail.